# How to provide a way for Chef users to de-register their disposable Vagrant VM?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I've been wrestling with this one for a while, figured I would open it up to the stackoverflow community:

I've got a setup where multiple developers can clone and spin up a Vagrant VM which will get provisioned with Chef. The VM has a hostname unique for the user, based on the host's hostname.

If a user wants to destroy and recreate it, they are instructed to use `vagrant destroy`, which, with the help of the `vagrant-butcher` plugin, will de-register the VM from Chef.

However, inevitably, users will `rm -rf` their VM and attempt to re-create it, getting the dreaded HTTP 403 Forbidden from Chef, because the VM is already registered with a different key.

I then have to manually delete the node and client from Chef, then have them try it again.

Has anyone ever through of a creative way of providing a user a way of de-registering an obsolete VM to be able to re-use the name (assuming both the .pem key and the vagrant folder is gone)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following script :-)

```
knife client delete $(hostname) -y
knife node delete $(hostname) -y
```

## Update

Avoid using a shared development environment. Use test kitchen to create a stand-alone test driven development environment. Under the hood it can still use vagrant with [chef zero](https://github.com/chef/chef-zero) (in memory chef server)

http://kitchen.ci/

Even better news is that test kitchen comes pre-installed with the [chef development kit](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-dk/).

Comment: Alright, but I'm struggling with this: `knife` needs a `.chef` folder that contains a `knife.rb` file. This `knife.rb` file needs to point to a client_name and client_key that is tied to a user that has permission to delete any node... So what user and key is that? Do I make a generic admin user and everyone has the .pem file that let's them run knife commands and delete any client/node? Or is there another way?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create a user on the chef server and specify url, username and key inside the knife.rb file. If you're running open source chef server I think the user will have to be an admin in order to delete nodes. Unfortunately with great power comes great responsibility, handing out admin privs will mean everyone can delete any node or client..... Any other way.... I have updated my answer

Comment: It seems I would lose too many of the benefits from chef server. I regularly update the recipes on the chef server, and have all the nodes automatically poll the server server and update as needed. I may just go ahead and give an admin user to everyone behind the scenes to allow them to delete their client and nodes from a script.

Comment: @zedix Have you seen Berkshelf? Berkshelf enables each developer to test their code against the same set of cookbooks and thereby pre-test changes to your production chef server. I would advise you to keep investigating. Never a good idea to have shared development environment.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "shared development environment"? There is only one person developing Chef cookbooks (me). The rest of the users are using Vagrant VMs provisioned by Chef to do their software development (not Chef-related).

Comment: You may have a middle way solution: make a web hook which call knife on the chef server, this way the key stays on the chef server and you allow people to call this url to clean their vm (name in parameter, whatever method you like there)

Comment: @Tensibai yes, that's what I was thinking, except it doesn't really prevent people from deleting nodes that don't belong to them (name is a parameter so you could pass whatever you want). I've implemented the solution using knife and a shared .pem admin key for now.

Comment: @zedix namespace the nodes with user name, use kerberos or at least basic Auth to ensure the user deleting a node is deleting one of his nodes ;)